# Insert data asynchronously into database using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous

I have a method in my repository that inserts data using Entity Framework. I need to convert this method to an async method. How I can do that?

This is my method:

```
public void movetosecondpost(ProcessingPost processingPost)
{
        SuccessPost movedQueue = new SuccessPost();
        movedPost.Id = processingPost.Id;
        Context.ProcessingPost.Remove(processingPost);
        Context.SuccessPost.Add(movedPost);
}
```

In my context I have these 2 save methods:

```
   public override int SaveChanges()
   {
        return base.SaveChanges();
   }

   public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to make this method (`movetosecondpost`) asynchronous since it does not involve any asynchronous work (e.g. IO). You could have made it asynchronous if it included saving changes to the database.

If there is a method that calls this method and then invokes `SaveChanges`, then you could make that method asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

A method can only be async when you mark it as such with the `async` keyword:

```
public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

You can now use the `await` keyword to unwrap the result of your `Task<int>` into an `int`. That's basically the difference between returning a `Task<int>` and an `int`. The task is just a promise: *I will do an operation which will return an int, but I don't know exactly when.*
While the changes are being made to the database, there is nothing your thread can do except wait until it's finished, so by doing it asynchronous your thread will be moved back to the threadpool while that is happening. As soon as the database operations are finished, another thread is grabbed from the threadpool and your method continues.

Comment: what change I need to have in my movetosecondpost method?

Comment: @Alma In that method you don't do anything that could benefit from being async. The creating/adding/removing entities from your context all happens in memory. Only when you call `SaveChanges` IO is being performed, and **that's** where async comes into the picture.

Comment: His SaveChanges already was async. The async modifier is an implementation detail of the method being called. The caller cannot detect that async was used. What this proposed code does it create a "proxy task" but nothing else changes.

Comment: Good explanation of use of the keyword "await"